# c questions about hashtable

Tags: c++, hashtable

The following is some code to pre process a hash table:

```
unsigned long cryptTable[0x500];
void StringHash::InitCryptTable() 
{  
    unsigned long seed = 0x00100001, index1 = 0, index2 = 0, i; 

    for( index1 = 0; index1 < 0x100; index1++ ) 
    {  
        for( index2 = index1, i = 0; i < 5; i++, index2 += 0x100 ) 
        {  
            unsigned long temp1, temp2; 
            seed = (seed * 125 + 3) % 0x2AAAAB; 
            temp1 = (seed & 0xFFFF) << 0x10; 
            seed = (seed * 125 + 3) % 0x2AAAAB; 
            temp2 = (seed & 0xFFFF); 
            cryptTable[index2] = ( temp1 | temp2 );  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Is there Anyone can tell me why seed = 0x00100001 and the following algorithm, why don't just do memset(cryptTable, 0, sizeof(cryptTable)), what's the benifit of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple aspect in this part of the code. At first you should read generally about cryptography and random generators.

- 0x00100001 - is just good as any other
- 0x2AAAAB=2796203 is prime and iterating seed = (seed * 125 + 3) % 0x2AAAAB will give you pseudo-random sequence of numbers from 0...2796202
- seed & 0xFFFF will give you 16 bits of pseudo random numbers

according to second part - it depend where it is used...